# Rendering Grease Pencil animation?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

What is the workflow for rendering/exporting grease pencil animation? Seems that the new updates for 2.78 are intended to make the grease pencil a production ready tool for making 2D animation in 3D spsce. There must be a way to render, right?

Comment: In version 2.79, a grease layer still cannot be rendered directly on top of 3D objects (except using `OpenGL Render` as explained in the answers -- But this rendering is a preview for the 3D objects, not a true one). However GP layers can be rendered and composited with the true 3D rendering, as explained in this video: [Quick Grease Pencil composition with Blender](https://youtu.be/vSD5mN7LT_g) which is linked by [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/grease_pencil/animating.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render grease pencil animation you have to go to Render>OpenGL Render Animation. Render will have dimensions set in Render properties so it's best to draw while in camera view to avoid stretching.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to render with opengl, using the menu or the icon:

[image]

but this can't be enough in some cases...