# How to make quick 2d animation with blender? Npr

Tags: rendering, animation, freestyle, npr

I don't know much about blender at all but I want to make 3d animations but wanting it to look 2d. 3d animations that try to look 2d are clearly 3d and I know it can be done with npr and freestyle but I don't know where to start. How do I make a 2d toon animations on blender? Something that can load in blender quickly. I'm assumeing that there's a way to make animation quickly with blender by using some trick of turning the 3d to 2d.

The reason I'm asking is cause rendering takes way to long and wondering if a sort of "2d" render would help. Even if itshe just line art if it renders faster. Takes a minute to render a image of toon style Suzanne.

I don't have special sharers or nodes. I don't even know how to use nodes yet, but is it even possible to make quick animations? Sorry for my hard question I been looking for the answer for weeks now.

Comment: This is too broad a question. Please show us what you are trying to achieve then we can help you.

Comment: You can turn off much of Blender's rendering "features" as they probably contribute to a 3D look. Then use the Freestyle option, it draws an outline around your objects. Also compositing can help reduce colours etc. But it sounds like you may want to look at the Grease pencil tool set.

Comment: If you just want a rendered preview you can use OpenGL render of the material or textured viewport, or just wait for EEVEE

Comment: about Grease Pencil, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66003/rendering-grease-pencil-animation

Comment: Is there a way to render only the camera's view? And only the end of the mesh. Like not looking for edges just the end of the mesh itself. Or would I have to make a custom render/tool for that?

Comment: I made this list
But it is in Arabic
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb9FctNAr4Krp_2Q7rQE-pul9-zLvGxif

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if this will answer your question, but I have done 2D animation before using blender 2.79 and now its much easier now with blender 2.8, because Eevee can render out your project in seconds.

What I do is that I import the cartoon 2D images as textures on a 2D plane with the same shape of the object or character, and then setup the camera as orthographic to see the plane in 2D, then make a rig for that plane and animate it, after that render it out with eevee, 1 frame renders in less than a second.

I am explaining all that in a step by step 2 video tutorial you can check it out and see if this method will help you out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD-RM2SMek0&t=314s

Answer (score 1):

Try the grease pencil.

> Grease Pencil is a particular type of Blender object that allow you to draw in the 3D space. Can be use to make traditional 2D animation, cut-out animation, motion graphics or use it as storyboard tool among other things.

https://www.blender.org/features/grease-pencil/