# Blender: Rendering volumetric stroke dots of the Grease Pencil?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

In Blender: is there any way to turn the dots of a volumetric stroke (when using the grease pencil) into renderable dots? So to actually see the dots when rendering the image?

[image: volumetric-stroke-blender]

Comment: Blender Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering Grease Pencil animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66003/rendering-grease-pencil-animation)